# Attach button next to side menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Simple Side Nav: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/

I want to attach a button next to side of this Nav, on the Right Side which I will be using to hide and show the Nav Bar.

I have created a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4q08khy1/

This button is the position i want it to be, as you can see in the image:

[image]

But it is hiding behind the Content Part of the page, is there a way to fix this?

my Left Nav:

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="sidebar-brand">
            <a href="#">
                Start Bootstrap
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Events</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="toggle"><span> << </span></a>
</div>
```

and Style on `toggle`

```
<style>
    .toggle {
        background: #1ABC9C;
        color: #eee;
        position: absolute;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        right: -50px;
        top: 18px;
        box-shadow: 5px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        z-index: 5000;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of the html to the fiddle?

Comment: the only other HTML is the Body and html tags

Comment: The problem is that you have the button inside the sidebar, and the sidebar needs `overflow:auto`. It will be better to use the button outside the sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding following CSS to your code:

```
a#menu-toggle {
   margin: -25px 0 0 -36px;
}
```

Comment: Not the button I wanted to place in that postion, but that will do. thanks. I was trying to place the <a class="toggle"> in that position, But this one seems better, Cheers